# Ошибка при исправлении которой появляется вторая.При исправлении второй появляется первая

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Помогите случилась ошибка.Есть программы:клиент и сервер.Но возникает ошибка `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` исправляю её появляется ошибка `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes`.Исправляю второю возвращается первая.Сервер работает исправно.Ошибки в клиенте,на строчку `if 'stop' in data:`
сервер:

```
import socket
import threading
import time
global conn
global data
HOST = ''
PORT = 2456
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected by',addr)
    def dzirdet():
        global conn
        global data
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print('client:'+data.decode('utf-8'))
    t = threading.Thread(target = dzirdet)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    data = ''
    while True:
        stop = 'stop'
        text = ''
        if stop in data:
            break
        while text == '':
            time.sleep(0.5)
            text = input('')
        conn.sendall(text.encode('utf-8'))
        if stop in text:
            break
    print('Disconnected',addr)
    conn.close()
```

клиент:

```
import socket
import threading
import time
global s
global data
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 2456
stop = 'stop'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
def dzirdet():
    global s
    global data
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print('server:'+data.decode('utf-8'))
t = threading.Thread(target = dzirdet)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
data = ''
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if 'stop' in data:
        break
    text = ''
    while text == '':
        text = input('')
    s.sendall(text.encode('utf-8'))
    if stop in text:
        break
s.close()
```

Comment: `if b"stop" in data`?

Comment: `if stop in data:` а ты указываешь тип строку: `'stop'` вот тебе и ошибка